# Flutter Firestore: An error occurred while parsing query arguments on using whereNotIn and arrayContains at the same query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My query is:

```
snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('dialogs')
          .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
          .where('users', arrayContains: globals.user.userId)
          .where('readers', whereNotIn: [globals.user.userId])
          .orderBy('priority')
          .limit(1)
          .get();
```

I'm getting the above exception:

> Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/unknown] An error occurred while parsing query arguments, see native logs for more information.

I have found some notes on the official [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries):

- You can use at most one in, `not-in`, or `array-contains-any` clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query.
- You can't combine not-in with not equals !=.

All should be just fine in my case.

Also I have tried several things:

- If I remove only the `whereNotIn` line, everything is just fine.
- if I remove only the `arrayContains` line, everything is just fine.

Why am I getting a query parsing exception?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have index created for `users` and `readers` fields?

Comment: Hey @Simon thanks for helping. I'm getting the exception before I'm getting the link to create the index. So it's not indexed.

Comment: Hi @genericUser, did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

Firestore query [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) was not up to date (relevant for 04.04.21).

## More details

I have checked my android Logchats on android studio and found out that:

> Invalid Query. You cannot use 'not_in' filters with 'array_contains' filters.

While firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) says that:

> You can use at most one in, not-in, or array-contains-any clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query.

It was not mentioned on the Firebase documentation that `array-contains` cannot be at the same query along with `not-in`.

## Conclusion

If you are encountered with query parsing exception. The most updated and fastest way to get relevant information about the problem is to check your Logchats.

Comment: I have reported firebase support team about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Firestore Limitation**

Firebase firestore doesn't allow you to use whereNotIn and arrayContains in a single query. [see here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)
[image: firestore limitations image]

**SOLUTION**

Split the query, first get entires by

```
snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('dialogs')
      .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
      .where('users', arrayContains: globals.user.userId)
      //.where('readers', whereNotIn: [globals.user.userId]) <-- remove this
      .orderBy('priority')
      .limit(1)
      .get();
```

Then filter the received `snapshot` locally ( say in a for loop )
Though it will work but bear in mind that this will be a performance hit. So, the best approach is to avoid such queries.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey @M.AQIB thanks for replying. I'm facing cost issues with Firestore. Since Firestore charges you for each read you make, it gets very expensive on large scales. Of course you can read all the documents from a collection and then filter them on the client side, but it's missing the point (cutting costs!). BUT, I think your answer will help others, so you get my bounty, Enjoy! :)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer for future readers!