# Issue getting data with (too much) where clauses

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm brand new to Flutter and I've just encountered an error :
I'm trying to retrieve all documents in a collection with multiples where clauses.

I'm working with Flutter v.3.3.1, Iphone 13 Pro simulator (iOS 15.5) for running my test app, Firebase Firestore as database.

For some context, here's how my data looks like :

```
Users {
  uid,
  name,
  mail,
  budget : {min, max}
  (sub-collection) passes : {Ad1, Ad6, ...},
  (sub-collection) likes : {Ad3, Ad5, ...}
}
```

```
Ads {
  uid,
  title,
  price,
  surface,
  ...
}
```

I want to get all the ads between a certain range of values (budget min/max) that the current user hasn't declined or liked.

```
var querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ads')
    .where('price', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: userBudget.start)
    .where('price', isLessThanOrEqualTo: userBudget.end)
    .where('uid', whereNotIn: [...passedIds, ...matchesdIds]).get();
```

I've read Flutter Firestore doc about chaining where (using indexes, etc.) but couldn't figure how to do this.
Index seems not to be a proper solution for my problem.
I've tried things they recommended on the doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) but I still get this error :

```
An error occurred while parsing query arguments, this is most likely an error with this SDK. (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803f3d70 __exceptionPreprocess + 236
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018019814c objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000103a1e994 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util16ObjcThrowHandlerENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 540
    3   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000103a1ddc4 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util5ThrowENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 64
    4   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000103d7e3a0 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util20ThrowInvalidArgumentIJNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEES9_EEEvPKcDpRKT_ + 72
    5   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000103d7da1c _ZNK8firebase9firestore3api5Query17ValidateNewFilterERKNS0_4core6FilterE + 240
    6   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000103d7d160 _ZNK8firebase9firestore3api5Query6FilterERKN
Lost connection to device.
```

So, any help is welcomed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on Firestore's [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

You're trying to have such conditions on two fields (`price` and `uid`), which isn't possible.

Also see:

- [Flutter Firestore: An error occurred while parsing query arguments on using whereNotIn and arrayContains at the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891023/flutter-firestore-an-error-occurred-while-parsing-query-arguments-on-using-wher)
- [Flutter Firebase using whereIn and WhereNotIn crashes Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971458/flutter-firebase-using-wherein-and-wherenotin-crashes-flutter-app)

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer ! So, if I get it right, I can't combine those fields in my query ... Do you think about any solution in particular for this case ?
Moreover, WhereNotIn is scaled to 10 right ?

Comment: The workaround for this limitation of Firestore's queries is to filter for one condition in the database, and perform the rest of the filtering in your appliction code.

Comment: That's what I started to do, thanks for your help man :)